# Problema con consulta SQL ejercicio

Tags: sql, subconsultas

Estoy en un curso de iniciación a SQL, he empezado desde 0, y estoy teniendo problemas con uno de los ejercicios:

Obtener, para cada persona, su nombre, así como el máximo número de roles diferentes
que haya asumido en una misma película. Mostrar únicamente aquellas personas que, en
alguna película, hayan asumido más de un rol diferente.

Siendo las tablas útiles para la consulta las siguientes:

```
CREATE TABLE movies.tb_genre ( 
   genre_id          INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   genre_name        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
   created_by_user   VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'OS_SGAD',
   created_date      DATE,
   updated_date      DATE
);


CREATE TABLE movies.tb_movie ( 
   movie_id          INTEGER      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   movie_title       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   movie_date        DATE,
   movie_format      VARCHAR(50),
   movie_genre_id    INTEGER,
   created_by_user   VARCHAR(10)  DEFAULT 'OS_SGAD', 
   created_date      DATE, 
   updated_date      DATE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_movie_genre FOREIGN KEY (movie_genre_id) REFERENCES movies.tb_genre (genre_id)
);


CREATE TABLE movies.tb_role ( 
   role_id           INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   role_name         VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
   created_by_user   VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'OS_SGAD',
   created_date      DATE,
   updated_date      DATE
);


CREATE TABLE movies.tb_person ( 
   person_id          INTEGER      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   person_name        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   person_country     VARCHAR (40),
   person_dob         DATE         NOT NULL,
   person_dod         DATE,
   person_parent_id   INTEGER,
   created_by_user    VARCHAR(10)  DEFAULT 'OS_SGAD', 
   created_date       DATE, 
   updated_date       DATE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_person_parent FOREIGN KEY (person_parent_id) REFERENCES movies.tb_person (person_id)
);


CREATE TABLE movies.tb_movie_person ( 
   movie_id           INTEGER     NOT NULL, 
   person_id          INTEGER     NOT NULL, 
   role_id            INTEGER     NOT NULL,
   movie_award_ind    CHAR(1)     NOT NULL,
   created_by_user    VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'OS_SGAD', 
   created_date       DATE, 
   updated_date       DATE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_movie_person PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, person_id, role_id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_movie FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies.tb_movie (movie_id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_person FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES movies.tb_person (person_id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_role FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES movies.tb_role (role_id)
);
```

He llegado como máximo a hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT p.person_name, MAX (m.role_id) AS MaxRole
    FROM movies.tb_person p, movies.tb_movie_person m
  WHERE p.person_id = m.person_id
 GROUP BY p.person_name
 HAVING COUNT (m.role_id) > 1;
```

Pero lógicamente no me lo clasifica por películas, y por mucho que le doy vueltas no encuentro la solución... Podrían echarme una mano? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué tu llave primaria en la segunda tabla se compone de 3 columnas?

Comment: La llave primaria debería ser única y dudo que esos 3 valores no se repitan en algún momento

Comment: Añado todas las tablas por si es de ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás muy cerca, solo tienes que agrupar también por película (aunque no aparezca en el SELECT) y obtendrás el resultado deseado.

Como nota adicional, es importante que aprendas a usar la sintaxis actualizada para unir tablas mediante el operador JOIN. Este operador fue agregado desde 1992 y la forma que utilizaste no se debería seguir enseñando. La consulta quedaría así.

```
SELECT p.person_name, MAX (m.role_id) AS MaxRole
    FROM movies.tb_person p
    JOIN movies.tb_movie_person m ON p.person_id = m.person_id
 GROUP BY p.person_name, m.movie_id
 HAVING COUNT (m.role_id) > 1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has salvado (no sabía que podía usar más de una columna en ORDER BY y llevaba ya dos días comiéndome la cabeza).

Answer (score 0):

> Aqui referencia una clave foranea a la misma tabla, se puede deber a eso.

```
CONSTRAINT fk_person_parent FOREIGN KEY (person_parent_id) REFERENCES movies.tb_person (person_id)
```

Comment: Añado todas las tablas por si es de ayuda. Gracias.